# Tengo dos imágenes guardadas en la base de datos de php my admin, pero cuando las edito desde el panel de administrador una de ellas no se actualiza

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

En mi base de datos tengo dos imágenes diferentes, una a la que he llamado 'slider' y otra a la que he llamado 'imagen', cuando actualizo las imágenes desde el panel de administración, la imagen a la que he llamado 'imagen' no se actualiza y el código para recogerlas y editarlas es exactamente igual en ambas. Les dejo el código con el fin de que puedan ayudarme.

````
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
//almacena los datos del formulario
    $id=$sanear($_POST['id']);
    $nombre=$sanear($_POST['nombre']);
    $descripcion=$sanear($_POST['descripcion']);
    $imagenGuardada=$sanear($_POST['imagenGuardada']);
    $otraimagenGuardada=$sanear($_POST['otraimagenGuardada']);

//Recoge las imágenes nuevas en el caso de que el usuario las cambie
    $slider=$_FILES['slider'];
    $imagen=$_FILES['imagen'];
//Valida que los campos no estén vacíos,
 if(empty($nombre)){
    $errores.='<li> No hay ningún nombre </li>';
    };
    if(empty($descripcion)){
    $errores.='<li> No hay ninguna descripción </li>';
    };
//Si el usuario no ha cambiado las imágenes, su valor no es alterado, por lo que serán las mismas que estaban en la BBDD. Si por el contrario el usuario introduce una imagen nueva el programa comprueba que este archivo sea una imagen
   
 if(empty($slider['tmp_name'])){
        $slider=$imagenGuardada;
    }else{
    $comprobar=getImagesize($slider['tmp_name']);
    if($comprobar===false){$errores.='<li> Debe introducir una imagen </li>';
    }else{
       $rutaDestino=$admin_config['carpetaImg'].$slider['name'];
       move_uploaded_file($slider['tmp_name'],$rutaDestino);
       $slider=$slider['name'];
 }};

 //$slider e $imagen son arrays asociativos, los datos que se envían a la BBDD lo hacen mediante el valor asignado en la posición 'nombre' de este Array.
   
    if(empty($imagen['tmp-name'])){
        $imagen=$otraimagenGuardada;
    }else{
    $comprobar=getImagesize($imagen['tmp-name']);
    if ($comprobar===false){$errores.='<li> Debe introducir una imagen </li>';
    }else{
        $rutaDestino=$admin_config['carpetaImg'].$imagen['name'];
        move_uploaded_file($imagen['tmp_name'],$rutaDestino);
        $imagen=$imagen['name'];
    }
    };```
````

Comment: ¿Lo de `$sanear($_POST['descripcion'])` (y similares) no te da ningún error? ¿Lo tienes así en el código original o el `$` ha aparecido al transcribirlo aquí? Además, utilizas `$imagen` como array asociativo y después haces un `$imagen=$imagen['name']`, que no tiene sentido. Podrías utilizar nombres diferentes para variables diferentes

Comment: También... otro tema es que hablas de phpMyAdmin (me imagino que hablas de la base de datos, quizá MySQL). Además de subir los archivos, ¿actualizas la base de datos con los nombres (¿y/o rutas?) nuevos?

Comment: Hola buenas VFG, lo de $sanear lo tengo en funciones disculpa por no subir esa parte del código pero no me da errores, ya he conseguido solucionarlo, metiendo ambas variables de las imágenes en el mismo condicional, ya se actualizan ambas, muchas gracias por tu ayuda:)

Comment: De acuerdo, pero si es una función imagino que irá sin el `$`, ¿no?

Comment: Por favor, elimina a PHPMyAdmin de la pregunta: aquí no tiene nada que ver la herramienta que estás utilizando para trabajar con la base de datos. ¿Es MySQL, MariaDB? Además, no olvides [aceptar](/help/accepted-answer) tu respuesta cuando transcurra el tiempo mínimo.

Answer (score 0):

He cambiado el orden del código, comprobando ambas variables de las imágenes en un mismo condicional, y ya se actualizan ambas.

````
//Si el usuario no ha cambiado las imágenes, su valor no es alterado, serán las mismas que estaban en la BBDD. Si por el contrario el usuario introduce una imagen nueva el programa comprueba que este archivo sea una imagen
    if(empty($slider['tmp_name'].$imagen['tmp_name'])){
        $slider=$imagenGuardada;
        $imagen=$otraimagenGuardada;
    }else{
    $comprobar=getImagesize($slider['tmp_name']);
    $comprobar=getImagesize($imagen['tmp_name']);

    if($comprobar===false){$errores.='<li> Debe introducir una imagen </li>';
    }else{
       $rutaDestino=$admin_config['carpetaImg'].$slider['name'];
       $otrarutaDestino=$admin_config['carpetaImg'].$imagen['name'];
       move_uploaded_file($slider['tmp_name'],$rutaDestino);
       move_uploaded_file($imagen['tmp_name'],$otrarutaDestino);
       $slider=$slider['name'];
       $imagen=$imagen['name'];
 }};```
````

Comment: Bueno... lo de meter todo en el mismo if... está bien pero date cuenta que sólo estás comrpobando la `$imagen` porque justo después de `$comprobar=getImagesize($slider['tmp_name']);` lo machacas con `$comprobar=getImagesize($imagen['tmp_name']);`. Pero ya no te doy más la lata. Y si estás satisfecha con esa solución, adelante.